# Receiving play integrity token, trouble decrypting on compactjws step

Tags: java, android, encryption, decode, google-play-integrity-api

Currently running into this error when ying to decode locally a play integrity response token. My code is very similar to this process, and it is failing in this [line](https://github.com/herzhenr/spic-android/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/henrikherzig/playintegritychecker/attestation/playintegrity/AttestationCallPlayIntegrity.kt#L227)

this is the error:
`javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT`

I am running a prod debug version to test. i know it is possible that because it is not the play store version it might be causing this problem but i am not sure.

i have tried decoding locally on my application and tried decoding locally using the above SPIC-android application but i run into the same problem.